# Expose mutli containers with 1 alb in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U4oY.png)

I am using one alb and a target group of port 80 listener. I have defined three containers through ecs task-definition and they have containerports of 9090, 9100 and 8080 respectively. I want to associate the above mentioned alb with all three containers, but only one container mapping is possible in console. Any solution?

Additionally, I'm curious about the difference between alb's listener and docker container's hostport. I want to unify the hostports of the three containers to 80, but in the task-definition stage, aws says that the hostports must not all be the same. Shouldn't the hostport be 80 to be mapped to port 80, the listener of alb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create three target groups, each pointing to a different container/port. Then in the ALB you would define multiple listeners with different paths that point to the different target groups.

> Additionally, I'm curious about the difference between alb's listener
> and docker container's hostport.

The ALB's listener port is the port a client like a web browser uses to connect to the ALB. The ECS container's port is the port the ALB uses to connect to the container. They are entirely separate.